# Node with Mac m1

Tags: node.js, npm, apple-m1, rosetta

I am having problems with node and my macOS with arm processor. I have already followed the whole [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65342769/install-node-on-m1-mac) on this other post.
I tried to do a clean install of node for arm with rosetta2, but if I run `node -p "process.arch"` I always get `x64`.

Since I have already removed and reinstalled node 5 times just today, could you please help me to find out how can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: if i run file `$(which node)` i get /Users/.nvm/versions/node/v18.10.0/bin/node: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED! I:

- Removed all Node files, everything, in all folders and subfolder making sure that node was completely uninstalled
- Removed the libraries and removed the dependencies
- Re-installed Node with brew (using arch)
- Re-installed libraries and dependencies

Last but not least, a fresh restart of the Mac since yarn was not working anymore (with segmentation fault).

Comment: This worked for me, but I used nvm to uninstall node (nvm uninstall 18) and then re-install the same version (nvm install 18). I also received the segmentation fault from yarn, which required a reboot.