rails on M2: dyld[...]: missing symbol called with ruby 2.5.1
I've new mac m2 and install rails env for old project using rails 5.1.6 and ruby 2.5.1
$ rvm list
=* ruby-2.5.1 [ broken ]

$ rails -v     
Rails 5.1.6.2

$ rails s
dyld[40663]: missing symbol called
Abort trap: 6

I've install ruby with command
rvm install 2.5.1 --with-out-ext=fiddle

Does any one have ideal to fix this? Thanks!

maybe try to re-install with rvm install 2.5.1 or maybe use another ruby version

@AntonBogdanov  I'm trying to reinstall 2 time but after reinstall it is same error.
$ rvm install 2.5.1
Already installed ruby-2.5.1.
To reinstall use:
rvm reinstall ruby-2.5.1

There are many questions regarding this with varying solutions based on the dependencies however they almost all appear to revolve around node.js, For Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74184647/node-m1-mac-dyld-missing-symbol-called, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447424/rails-on-m2-dyld-missing-symbol-called, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203712/mac-m1-dyld-missing-symbol-called-on-ruby-arm64-installation-via-rvm

Let try asdf https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html

This post has a great explanation of this common problem on M1, M2, or M3 Macs. https://www.rubyonmac.dev/how-to-install-therubyracer-on-m1-m2-apple-silicon-mac
