M1 chip Mac, cant use nvm to install node v14
enter image description here
im try to use nvm install node v14 , but not word, and i also try to use arch -86_64 zsh, alert some error arch: posix_spawnp: zsh: Bad CPU type in executable
$ nvm uninstall 14
$ arch -x86_64 zsh 
$ nvm install 14
$ nvm alias default 14

i just want to install node v14 in my M1 chip Mac

Cross reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67907214/18667225
